# Strange line that suddenly appeared

Tags: haskell, vim

I have been using vim for like a year and never made any change pertaining to underline. But all of a sudden vim starts to underline almost every keyword in the Haskell file.

I searched through vimrc and did not find any change specifically made for Haskell file.

My question is, is there any way to turn off the underline? It is visually distracting and annoying.

Below is how the file looks like right now 
[image]

Comment: do you install a lint or on-the-fly checker? try to open a file that compiles well and see if such problem exists.

Comment: Have you recently updated your system or some part of it?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr I am using ale and the problem seems indeed related to this tool. Following Daniel's suggestions, the vim now would underline the code for which the compiler suggests syntactic improvement.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you have turned on spell check. Try

```
:setlocal nospell
```

to turn it off for the current buffer. You can put a line like this in `~/.vim/ftplugin/haskell.vim` to turn it off for all Haskell files.

Comment: Turning off spell check solves part of the problem. Some have disappeared but some still linger around.

Comment: It seems the remaining bit of the problem is related to ale lint tool. On those lines where the lint suggests an improvement the code would be underlined, but otherwise it is pretty alright.